# How can I run a project in a local server using Pycharm?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

when I try to run a project in a local server using Pycharm, I can't do that with these errors.

So would you mind telling me how should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

---

**updated:** 
I found that global_settings.py doesn't exist in the directory of conf, and I made another question to solve the newest issue.
Thank you.
[How should I do when conf folder doesn't have global_setteings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800842/how-should-i-do-when-conf-folder-doesnt-have-global-setteings-py)

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.conf import global_settings
ImportError: cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf' (/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**init**.py

```
"""
Settings and configuration for Django.

Read values from the module specified by the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment
variable, and then from django.conf.global_settings; see the global_settings.py
for a list of all possible variables.
"""

import importlib
import os
import time
import traceback
import warnings
from pathlib import Path

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.utils.deprecation import (
    RemovedInDjango30Warning, RemovedInDjango31Warning,
)
from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty

ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"

DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_DEPRECATED_MSG = 'The DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE setting is deprecated.'
FILE_CHARSET_DEPRECATED_MSG = (
    'The FILE_CHARSET setting is deprecated. Starting with Django 3.1, all '
    'files read from disk must be UTF-8 encoded.'
)


class SettingsReference(str):
    """
    String subclass which references a current settings value. It's treated as
    the value in memory but serializes to a settings.NAME attribute reference.
    """
    def __new__(self, value, setting_name):
        return str.__new__(self, value)

    def __init__(self, value, setting_name):
        self.setting_name = setting_name


class LazySettings(LazyObject):
    """
    A lazy proxy for either global Django settings or a custom settings object.
    The user can manually configure settings prior to using them. Otherwise,
    Django uses the settings module pointed to by DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
    """
    def _setup(self, name=None):
        """
        Load the settings module pointed to by the environment variable. This
        is used the first time settings are needed, if the user hasn't
        configured settings manually.
        """
        settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
        if not settings_module:
            desc = ("setting %s" % name) if name else "settings"
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
                "You must either define the environment variable %s "
                "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
                % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

    def __repr__(self):
        # Hardcode the class name as otherwise it yields 'Settings'.
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            return '<LazySettings [Unevaluated]>'
        return '<LazySettings "%(settings_module)s">' % {
            'settings_module': self._wrapped.SETTINGS_MODULE,
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            self._setup(name)
        val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
        self.__dict__[name] = val
        return val

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """
        Set the value of setting. Clear all cached values if _wrapped changes
        (@override_settings does this) or clear single values when set.
        """
        if name == '_wrapped':
            self.__dict__.clear()
        else:
            self.__dict__.pop(name, None)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        """Delete a setting and clear it from cache if needed."""
        super().__delattr__(name)
        self.__dict__.pop(name, None)

    def configure(self, default_settings=global_settings, **options):
        """
        Called to manually configure the settings. The 'default_settings'
        parameter sets where to retrieve any unspecified values from (its
        argument must support attribute access (__getattr__)).
        """
        if self._wrapped is not empty:
            raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
        holder = UserSettingsHolder(default_settings)
        for name, value in options.items():
            setattr(holder, name, value)
        self._wrapped = holder

    @property
    def configured(self):
        """Return True if the settings have already been configured."""
        return self._wrapped is not empty

    @property
    def DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE(self):
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        # Show a warning if the setting is used outside of Django.
        # Stack index: -1 this line, -2 the caller.
        filename, _line_number, _function_name, _text = stack[-2]
        if not filename.startswith(os.path.dirname(django.__file__)):
            warnings.warn(
                DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_DEPRECATED_MSG,
                RemovedInDjango30Warning,
                stacklevel=2,
            )
        return self.__getattr__('DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE')

    @property
    def FILE_CHARSET(self):
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        # Show a warning if the setting is used outside of Django.
        # Stack index: -1 this line, -2 the caller.
        filename, _line_number, _function_name, _text = stack[-2]
        if not filename.startswith(os.path.dirname(django.__file__)):
            warnings.warn(
                FILE_CHARSET_DEPRECATED_MSG,
                RemovedInDjango31Warning,
                stacklevel=2,
            )
        return self.__getattr__('FILE_CHARSET')


class Settings:
    def __init__(self, settings_module):
        # update this dict from global settings (but only for ALL_CAPS settings)
        for setting in dir(global_settings):
            if setting.isupper():
                setattr(self, setting, getattr(global_settings, setting))

        # store the settings module in case someone later cares
        self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module

        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

        tuple_settings = (
            "INSTALLED_APPS",
            "TEMPLATE_DIRS",
            "LOCALE_PATHS",
        )
        self._explicit_settings = set()
        for setting in dir(mod):
            if setting.isupper():
                setting_value = getattr(mod, setting)

                if (setting in tuple_settings and
                        not isinstance(setting_value, (list, tuple))):
                    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The %s setting must be a list or a tuple. " % setting)
                setattr(self, setting, setting_value)
                self._explicit_settings.add(setting)

        if not self.SECRET_KEY:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

        if self.is_overridden('DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE'):
            warnings.warn(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango30Warning)
        if self.is_overridden('FILE_CHARSET'):
            warnings.warn(FILE_CHARSET_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango31Warning)

        if hasattr(time, 'tzset') and self.TIME_ZONE:
            # When we can, attempt to validate the timezone. If we can't find
            # this file, no check happens and it's harmless.
            zoneinfo_root = Path('/usr/share/zoneinfo')
            zone_info_file = zoneinfo_root.joinpath(*self.TIME_ZONE.split('/'))
            if zoneinfo_root.exists() and not zone_info_file.exists():
                raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
            # Move the time zone info into os.environ. See ticket #2315 for why
            # we don't do this unconditionally (breaks Windows).
            os.environ['TZ'] = self.TIME_ZONE
            time.tzset()

    def is_overridden(self, setting):
        return setting in self._explicit_settings

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%(cls)s "%(settings_module)s">' % {
            'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
            'settings_module': self.SETTINGS_MODULE,
        }


class UserSettingsHolder:
    """Holder for user configured settings."""
    # SETTINGS_MODULE doesn't make much sense in the manually configured
    # (standalone) case.
    SETTINGS_MODULE = None

    def __init__(self, default_settings):
        """
        Requests for configuration variables not in this class are satisfied
        from the module specified in default_settings (if possible).
        """
        self.__dict__['_deleted'] = set()
        self.default_settings = default_settings

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._deleted:
            raise AttributeError
        return getattr(self.default_settings, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._deleted.discard(name)
        if name == 'DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE':
            warnings.warn(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango30Warning)
        elif name == 'FILE_CHARSET':
            warnings.warn(FILE_CHARSET_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango31Warning)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        self._deleted.add(name)
        if hasattr(self, name):
            super().__delattr__(name)

    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(
            s for s in [*self.__dict__, *dir(self.default_settings)]
            if s not in self._deleted
        )

    def is_overridden(self, setting):
        deleted = (setting in self._deleted)
        set_locally = (setting in self.__dict__)
        set_on_default = getattr(self.default_settings, 'is_overridden', lambda s: False)(setting)
        return deleted or set_locally or set_on_default

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%(cls)s>' % {
            'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
        }


settings = LazySettings()
```

Python Console

```
import sys;
...
...print(sys.path)
['/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev', '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/third_party/thriftpy', '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django']
```

Run/Debug Configurations in Pycharm

```
[ Script path ]: /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py

[ Parameters ]:runserver

[ Environment ] variables:PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings_dev

[ Python interpreter ]:Python 3.7(project_django) ~/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/bin/python

[ Working directory ]:/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project
```

Development environment

- Mac: mojave 10.14.6
- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2
- Pycharm: 2019.3.1 (community edition)

Comment: Seems like an environment issue. Your Python interpreter in the Python console and during Runtime may be different. Check out your Python script path in the "Run Configuration" settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I checked the script path in the  "Run Configuration" settings.it is [ /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py ].is this the cause of my issue?

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf'` Instead try to import `settings` from `django.conf`

Comment: My recommendation is that you launch your server outside PyCharm so that you can debug these kinds of issues properly without your editor being a variable in the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!, I tried that way(change django.conf)  but it still shows the error.[ImportError: cannot import name 'settings' from 'django.conf']

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried to launch my local server using a terminal(without pycharm), but in that case, it also shows the same error.

Comment: I found that global_settings.py doesn't exist in the directory of conf, and I made another question to solve the newest issue, thank you. How should I do when conf folder doesn't have global_setteings.py[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800842/how-should-i-do-when-conf-folder-doesnt-have-global-setteings-py ]