# How should I do when conf folder doesn't have global_setteings.py with an error [ cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf' ]?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I launch a Django project in a local server, It doesn't work with the errors below,
and then, I checked the directory of conf(/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf) and found that global_settings.py doesn't exist in that directory.

in that case, how should I do?

do I have to make the global_settings.py my self in there with [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py)? or will I be able to solve another way?

Would you mind telling me how should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**__init__.py**(global_settings has red lile)
[image]

**The structure of conf directory**

[image]

**error code after I add global_settings.py in the conf folder my self**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/harvest_timer/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/caches.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core import signals
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.dispatch import Signal
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.dispatch.dispatcher import Signal, receiver  # NOQA
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.utils.inspect import func_accepts_kwargs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.inspect'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**error code when I run the project using Pycharm**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.conf import global_settings
ImportError: cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf' (/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**error code when I run the project using the terminal**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.conf import global_settings
ImportError: cannot import name 'global_settings' from 'django.conf' (/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Python Console**

```
import sys;
...
...print(sys.path)
['/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev', '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/third_party/thriftpy', '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django']
```

**Run/Debug Configurations in Pycharm**

```
[ Script path ]: /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py

[ Parameters ]:runserver

[ Environment ] variables:PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings_dev

[ Python interpreter ]:Python 3.7(project_django) ~/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/bin/python

[ Working directory ]:/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project
```

**Development environment**

- Mac: mojave 10.14.6
- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2
- Pycharm: 2019.3.1 (community edition)

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't create global_settings yourself. 
I see you are using Pycharm, try your Python virtualenv interpreter to Pycharm with these instructions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html
Then try to start the django project from Pycharm

Comment: Thank you for your answer! actually I've already set a project Interpreter like this, python 3.7(project_django) ~GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/bin/python, and it has Django package. but I can't launch the project from Pycharm and terminal either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Django configured in your system.

I think what you are missing is activating your virtual environment.

cd to Django path. `/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/`
Run `source bin/activate` to activate your virtual environment
then cd to your project. All should be working fine then.

I am doing a lot of assumptions though. I am not sure of how exactly you have your development environment setup for django.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though I tried to make command runserver after I activate the virtual environment from the terminal in my Mac. it shows the same errors. and I add how to set the Run/Debug Configurations in Pycharm in the question.

Comment: Have you tried running just in terminal without pyCharm? You should run ```python manage.py runserver``` BTW, what's your projects name?

Comment: Yes, I have, I tried in the terminal without Pycharm, my project name is "project" so after I did cd project, I did this command "(venv) ApplenoMacBook-Pro:project apple$ python3 manage.py runserver"

Comment: I add the error code when I run the project using the terminal in the question, could you please check it?

Comment: I add the code of the manage.py file in the question, could you please check it?

Comment: You have a problem with your Django installation. Make sure you properly install django. I have a feeling the correct path to your django is /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django without the /venv/. ```'/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django'```.

Comment: thank you, before I try your new suggestion, could you please check the error code after I add global_settings.py in the conf folder my self I add in the question? can you see it is getting better?